# Glob no longer working with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, glob

**Edit**

There is nothing wrong with my code so feel free to use it as it is, if ever you need to search your file system from within PHP then echo the results.

---

I created a class to search through files using `glob`. It worked perfectly but now that I have migrated from Apache to Nginx, it always returns 0 results.

Here is my code:

```
public static function search($path, $find, $caseSensitive = false)
{
    if ($path[strlen($path) - 1] !== '/')
        $path .= '/';
    $path = '../'.$path;
    $pathLen = strlen($path);
    $path .= '*';
    if ($caseSensitive)
        $files = self::globRecursive($path.$find);
    else
    {
        $findLen = strlen($find);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $findLen; $i++)
            $find1 .= '['.strtolower($find[$i]).strtoupper($find[$i]).']';
        $files = self::globRecursive($path.$find1);
    }
    $message = '';
    $count = count($files);
    if ($count === 0)
        return '"'.$find.'" not found.';
    foreach ($files as $file)
        $message .= substr($file, $pathLen).'<br />';
    return '"'.$find.'" found in '.$count.' files:<br />'.$message;
}

private static function globRecursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
{
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
        $files = array_merge($files, self::globRecursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: `glob()` has nothing to do with either nginx or apache. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You are 100% correct. The problem is due to the change in root. Simply prepending `../` fixed the problem.

Comment: Anyway, hopefully my code will help a few people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to changing my root directy. Simply prepending `../` to my search query fixed the problem.